# Jackson-JsonLD nested Objects

Tags: java, jackson, schema.org, json-ld

I want to program a restful API and annotate my data with schema.org. For this I wanted to use Jackson-Jsonld. Annotating simple objects with jackson-jsonld were no problem, but complex ones with nested objects got me stucked. In my jsonld the simple attributes like id, name got anntotated but the nested location not.

I read about Serialization and that it should help in order to get the second object. However, after implementing my serialization part it seems that the serialization did not changed anything. 
Here is my sample output, the type for location should be PostalAddress however the type is missing:

```
{"@context":
    {"uri":"http://schema.org/url","name":"http://schema.org/name","location":"http://schema.org/location"},
    "@type":"http://schema.org/Organization",
    "uri":"http://localhost:8080/kangarooEvents/venue/12",
    "name":"Joondalup Library - Ground Floor Meeting Room",
    "location":{
         "address":"102 Boas Avenue",
         "city":"Joondalup",
         "zip":"6027",
         "country":"Australia",
         "state":"WA"},
    "@id":12}
```

I want to annotate an organization which has a single location:

```
@JsonldType("http://schema.org/Organization")
public class Venue {
    @JsonldId
    private Integer id;
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/url")
    private String uri;
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/name")
    private String name;
    @JsonSerialize(using = CostumLocationSerializer.class)
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/location")
    private Location location;
```

Location:

```
@JsonldType("http://schema.org/PostalAddress")
public class Location {
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/streetAddress")
    private String address;
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/addressLocality")
    private String city;
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/addressRegion")
    private String state;
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/addressRegion")
    private String country;
    @JsonldProperty("http://schema.org/postalCode")
    private String zipcode;
```

Serialization:

```
 public class CostumLocationSerializer extends StdSerializer<Location> {
      private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

      public CostumLocationSerializer(){
         this( null);

      }
      protected CostumLocationSerializer(Class<Location> t) {
          super(t);
      }

      @Override
     public void serialize(Location location, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException {
         jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
         jsonGenerator.writeStringField("address", location.getAddress());
         jsonGenerator.writeStringField("city", location.getCity());
         jsonGenerator.writeStringField("zip", location.getZipcode());
         jsonGenerator.writeStringField("country", location.getCountry());
         jsonGenerator.writeStringField("state", location.getState());
         jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
         String serialized = mapper.writeValueAsString(location);
     } 
}
```

I think that my problem might be in the serialization but I can not figure it out. Maybe someone annotated nested obj. and can tell me what my problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the `jackson-jsonld` part and do it manually

1. **Create JSON** - just introduce a field for `type` and `id` into your java classes.
2. **Create a JSON-LD context** - map your `id` and `type` fields in an additional `@context` object
3. **Combine context and data** - e.g. just add your `@context` object after your 'normal' json serialization using standard jackson API.

**Example**

```
@Test
public void createJsonFromPojo() throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    // Create object structure
    Venue venue = new Venue();
    venue.location = new Location();
    venue.id="12";
    venue.uri="http://localhost:8080/kangarooEvents/venue/12";
    venue.name="Joondalup Library - Ground Floor Meeting Room";
    venue.location.address="102 Boas Avenue";
    venue.location.city="Joondalup";
    venue.location.state="WA";
    venue.location.country="Australia";
    venue.location.zipcode="6027";

    //1. Create JSON 
    ObjectNode myData = mapper.valueToTree(venue);

    //2. Create a JSON-LD context
    ArrayNode context = mapper.createArrayNode();
    context.add("http://schema.org/");
    ObjectNode myContext=mapper.createObjectNode();
    myContext.put("id", "@id");
    myContext.put("type", "@type");
    context.add(myContext);

    //3. Combine context and data
    myData.set("@context",context);

    //4. Print
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true).writeValue(w, myData);
    String result= w.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
}

public class Venue {
    public final String type = "http://schema.org/Organization";
    public String id;
    public String uri;
    public String name;
    public Location location;
}

public class Location {
    public final String type = "http://schema.org/PostalAddress";
    public String address;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String country;
    public String zipcode;
}
```

**Gives you**

```
{ 
    "@context": [
        "http://schema.org/",
        {
          "id": "@id",
          "type":"@type"
        }
     ],
     "uri":"http://localhost:8080/kangarooEvents/venue/12",
     "name":"Joondalup Library - Ground Floor Meeting Room",
     "location":{
         "address":"102 Boas Avenue",
         "city":"Joondalup",
         "zip":"6027",
         "country":"Australia",
         "state":"WA",
         "type":"http://schema.org/PostalAddress"
      },
      "id":"12",
      "type":"http://schema.org/Organization"
}
```

[**View Example in Playground**](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-compacted&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%5B%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%22%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22%40type%22%7D%5D%2C%22uri%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2FkangarooEvents%2Fvenue%2F12%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22Joondalup%20Library%20-%20Ground%20Floor%20Meeting%20Room%22%2C%22location%22%3A%7B%22address%22%3A%22102%20Boas%20Avenue%22%2C%22city%22%3A%22Joondalup%22%2C%22zip%22%3A%226027%22%2C%22country%22%3A%22Australia%22%2C%22state%22%3A%22WA%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FPostalAddress%22%7D%2C%22id%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FOrganization%22%7D&frame=%7B%7D&context=%7B%7D)